# function that is its own inverse

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

$f(f(x))=x \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. I am trying to prove there exists an irrational $t$ such that $f(t)$ is also irrational.

I have been trying things like assume $t$ irrational implies $f(t)$ is rational and then $f(f(t)+t)$ is rational but $f(f(f(t)+t))=f(t)+t$ but I can't come up with a contradiction. Is there a less mind-boggling approach?

Comment: Hint: Observe that $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: Such a function is called an "involution", by the way.  It's one of my favorite fancy-math-words-describing-a-simple-concept.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is its own inverse. Then $f$ is injective: $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $a=f(f(a))=f(f(b))=b$.

Ok, now suppose that $f(t)$ is rational for every irrational $t$. Then we have an injection from the set of irrationals into the set of rationals, given by $t\mapsto f(t)$. But this is impossible, because the set of rational numbers is countable and the set of irrationals is not.

Comment: typo: $f(f(a))=f(f(b))$ (too small for me to edit)

Comment: @robjohn: Danke!